# How do I get WebView to load up over wifi?

Tags: java, android-webview

I can't seem to get my `WebView` to load up. I get a blank (white) activity instead of a webpage.

I have tried adding permissions for `ACCESS_WIFI_STATE` and `ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE` but these do not work? 
I get this error message :

```
07-13 04:02:18.570 18878-18878/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.packagename.phase1challenge, PID: 18878
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.packagename.phase1challenge/com.packagename.phase1challenge.WebViewActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2613)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1517)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:227)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6102)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:859)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:749)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
        at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:4450)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:4286)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:4227)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:4200)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:460)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:145)
        at com.packagename.phase1challenge.WebViewActivity.onCreate(WebViewActivity.java:20)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6280)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1131)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2566)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1517) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:227) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6102) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:859) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:749)
```

Here is the code:
public class WebViewActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
private WebView myWebView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_web);


    WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web_view);
    myWebView.loadUrl("https://url.com/alc/");

    }

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (myWebView.canGoBack()) {
        myWebView.goBack();
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
```

Layout res file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".WebViewActivity">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/web_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Manifest

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.packagename.phase1challenge">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".ProfileActivity" android:label="@string/profile_label" android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"/>
        <activity android:name=".WebViewActivity" android:label="@string/about_label" android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"/>
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:label="@string/main_label">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="preloaded_fonts"
            android:resource="@array/preloaded_fonts" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Can you please post error/debug logs here? Do you have the permission `android.permission.INTERNET` in your manifest? It does not have to be only Wi-Fi to access internet on your phone. It can be a data connection also, right?

Comment: Hi take a look at the question. I edited it for clarity. It looks like I am setting to a null pointer (line 20). I don't know what to do.

Comment: Can you please post your resource file please? It is the file from which you are trying to extract the webview using the id - R.id.web_view. Also, the exception does not state a null pointer exception (It's an IllegalStateException). So, I don't think it is an NPE.

Comment: Do I add the WebView settings in the activity with the button that opens the page or in the WebView activity?